# Ubuntu nohup shutdown specific script

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, nohup

lets say we do:

> sudo nohup ./start.sh process1
>
> sudo nohup ./start.sh process2
>
> sudo nohup ./start.sh process3

`./start.sh` is running a python file that loops forever.

Now, how do I kill the 'process2'?

I can do `killall python` and all of them would be shutdown.
Is it possible to kill 'proccess2' specifically somehow mark it or something?

Comment: try ; jobs -l and found pid and kill -9 <pid>

Comment: You can look at running processes: `ps -ef` and then grep for python or some other identification of your process: `ps -ef | grep python`

Comment: @M.Dogru I get nothing up when I do `jobs -l` weird. 

@andlrc Thanks, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/$1 &

user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ ./start.sh test1.py
user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ ./start.sh test1.py
user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ ./start.sh test1.py

user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ ps -ef | grep -i python
user   19447  2062  0 14:37 pts/32   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/test1.py
user   19449  2062  0 14:37 pts/32   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/test1.py
user   19451  2062  0 14:37 pts/32   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/test1.py
user   19454 11980  0 14:38 pts/32   00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i python
```

Second field is pid number.

```
user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ kill -9 19449

user@host:/tmp/pythontest$ ps -ef | grep -i python
user   19447  2062  0 14:37 pts/32   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/test1.py
user   19451  2062  0 14:37 pts/32   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /tmp/pythontest/test1.py
user   19457 11980  0 14:38 pts/32   00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i python
```